# What's the best practice to make a directory an importable package?

Tags: python

I created a few utility functions, all put into a folder, and later I created some scripts which import the functions in that folder, please see the following the structure of files,

```sh
root
|-- myutils  (folder with util python files)
|   |-- __init__.py  (empty)
|   |-- utils1.py
|   |-- utils2.py  (utils1 is imported by utils2)
|
|-- myscripts
|   |-- hello.py  (try to import utils1 and utils2)
```

Now the problem is I cannot import utils1/utils2 inside hello.py, here is what I tried

```py
# This is hello.py

import sys
sys.path.append("root")  # so that we can search root and find myutils

import myutils  # import myutils, this is OK and no errors

x = myutils.utils1.foo()  # ERROR: module 'myutils' has no attribute 'utils1'
```

How could I fix the error and what's the best practice for my use-case here?

Comment: The simple way is to move hello.py to root, and ditch the appending to sys.path, just import myutils/myutils.utils1

Comment: @barny Yes, that's a simple way, but I don't want to put my custom scripts and utility files into the same folder, which looks messy.

Comment: Try sticking plasters like making `myutils/__init__.py`  do `import ./utils1`. Or maybe hello.py should `import myutils.utils1` - but IMO your folder structure is going to be challenging, the need to modify `sys.path` is a red flag.